# FullCalendar Component in Vaadin import not working

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin24

Pretty much the title, i'm using [this Vaadin component](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/full-calendar-flow) to implement a calendar in my application.
This is the relevant part of my Pom.xml file:

```
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
                                /////////////

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.stefan</groupId>
            <artifactId>fullcalendar2</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I should be able to use this import, anywhere in my application:

```
import org.vaadin.stefan.ui.view.demos.entryproviders.EntryService;
```

But i can't i continuosly run into the error:

```
The import org.vaadin.stefan.ui cannot be resolvedJava(268435846)
```

Witch is very strange since the import should work.

Can you help me make org.vaadin.stefan.ui work?

Comment: The dependency / JAR file that you added through Maven does not contain that class. It's part of the project's demo module, which doesn't seem to be distributed through Maven: https://github.com/stefanuebe/vaadin_fullcalendar/blob/master/demo

Comment: hello Sascha is there any way to use that import ?

Comment: Why do you want to use it, it's only for demonstration purposes? Looking at the examples on the page that you linked, you are supposed to use an `EntryProvider` with the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sasha metioned this import is from the demos and it just for demostration.

```
import org.vaadin.stefan.ui.view.demos.entryproviders.EntryService;
```

If you want to use entryservice you have to manually create the java class and the package inside your own application.